# Find sibling in WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a xaml structure, that looks like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>            
    </TextBox>
    <ToolBarPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Funky stuff" Command="{Binding Query}" CommandParameter="{what to type in here?}" />
    </ToolBarPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

If user clicks the `Button` under `ToolBarPanel`, I want the content of `TextBox` to be passed as the `CommandParameter`. So how do I find this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name your Textbox and then bind you command parameter to the text property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="myText">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>            
    </TextBox>
    <ToolBarPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Funky stuff" 
                Command="{Binding Query}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=myText}" />
    </ToolBarPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps.